# How to determine if chunks of a value could fit into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6

Given an input array of `1`s and `0`s of arbitrary length, such as:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

How can I (most efficiently) calculate a new array detailing if chunks of size `n` `0`s which can fit into the input?

### Examples

Where output now means

- 1 == 'Yes a zero chunk that size could go here'
- 0 == 'Couldn't fit a chunk that size there'

---

- Chunk size = 1 (`[0]`): `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]`
- Chunk size = 2 (`[0,0]`): `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]`
- Chunk size = 3 (`[0,0,0]`): `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`
- Chunk size = 4 (`[0,0,0,0]`): `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

I'm using ES6, so any language features are fine.

EDIT:

The output shouldn't just be a 'yes'/'no' a chunk of size 'n' can fit in this array. More specifically, it needs to be an array of the same length, where a '1' / 'true' array value represents either:

- Yes, a chunk of size 'n' could start and fit here, ***or***
- Yes, this slot could contain a chunk of size 'n' that started before it

On that second point, this would mean for chunk size 3:

`input = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];`

`output = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0];`

Edit 2:

This is the function I came up with but it seems very inefficient:

```
const calculateOutput = (input, chunkSize) => {
  const output = input.map((value, index) => {
    let chunkFitsHere = false;

    const start = (index - (chunkSize) >= 0) ? index - (chunkSize) : 0;
    const possibleValues = input.slice(start, index + chunkSize);
    possibleValues.forEach((pValue, pIndex) => {
      let consecutives = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < possibleValues.length - 1; i += 1) {
        if (consecutives === chunkSize) {
          break;
        }
        if (possibleValues[i+1] === 0) {
          consecutives += 1;
        } else {
          consecutives = 0;
        }
      }
      if (consecutives === chunkSize) {
        chunkFitsHere = true;
      }
    });
    return chunkFitsHere ? 1 : 0;
  });
  return output;
};
```

Comment: please add how the chunk size affect the result. beside that, please add your code, you tried.

Comment: I will clarify the above and add a proper example of what I've tried soon — (had to abstract my original problem for the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the connected free places by reversing the array and take an flag for the last return value for mapping.

> Array before final mapping and after, depending on `n`
>
> ```
>  1  0  4  3  2  1  0  0  2  1  0  0  0  3  2  1  0  2  1  array with counter
>  1  0  4  4  4  4  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  3  3  3  0  2  2  array same counter
> -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ------------------
>  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  n = 1
>  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  n = 2
>  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  n = 3
>  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  n = 4
> ```

```js
function chunk(array, n) {
    return array
        .slice()
        .reverse()
        .map((c => v => v ? c = 0 : ++c)(0))
        .reverse()
        .map((l => v => l = v && (l || v))(0))
        .map(v => +(v >= n));
}

var array = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];

console.log(chunk(array, 1).join(' '));
console.log(chunk(array, 2).join(' '));
console.log(chunk(array, 3).join(' '));
console.log(chunk(array, 4).join(' '));
```

If you like only one mapping at the end, remove the last two `map` and use

```
.map((l => v => l = +(v && (v >= n || l)))(0));
```

for final mapping.

Comment: This solution is beautiful and has taught me that `Array.prototype.reverse()` exists! The counter is also very helpful to illustrate how it's checking the spaces around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse array **once**, calculating length of the series of zeros. If it is long enough, fill output with series of 1 of the same length.

Note that you can fill output for different chunk lengths **simultaneously** (filling chunks in rows of 2d array with row index not exceeding `zerolen`)

Python code:

```
def zerochunks(a, n):
    l = len(a)
    result = [0] * l   #list of l zeros

    zerolen = 0
    for i in range(l + 1):
        ### Short circuit evaluation to shorten code
        if (i==l) or (a[i] != 0):   
            if (zerolen >= n):   #series of zeros is finished here
                for j in range(i - zerolen, i):
                    result[j] = 1
            zerolen  = 0
        else:
            zerolen += 1

    return result

print(zerochunks([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 1))
print(zerochunks([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 2))
print(zerochunks([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 3))
print(zerochunks([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 4))
print(zerochunks([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 5))

>>> 
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And function for getting all arrays with chunks in maxn range:

```
def zerochunksall(a, maxn):
    l = len(a)
    result = [[0] * l for i in range(maxn)]

    zerolen = 0
    for i in range(l + 1):
        if (i==l) or (a[i] != 0):
            for k in range(0, zerolen):
                for j in range(i - zerolen, i):
                    result[k][j] = 1
            zerolen  = 0
        else:
            zerolen += 1

    return result

print(zerochunksall([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 5))
 >>
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this — Ideally, the solution needs to be in JS to help others. Will look into porting it into JS though as the algorithm is intriguing!

Comment: I don't know how to organize JS array/lists properly, so decided to demonstrate working code with Python. Hope porting is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.some` to check if the chunk can fit starting to some index of the input array. To check if the chunk with it's actual length can fit, you can use `array.prototype.every`:

```js
var input = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0];
var chunk = [0,0,0];
var res = input.some((e, i) => chunk.every((c, j) => input[i + j] === c));
console.log(res);
```

```js
var input = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0];
var chunk = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var res = input.some((e, i) => chunk.every((c, j) => input[i + j] === c));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fit(input, n) {
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var fit = true;
        for(var j = i; j < i + n; j++) {
            if(j >= input.length || input[j]) {  // either over the array size or occupied
                fit = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        output.push(fit);
    }
    return output;
}

var input = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
console.log(fit(input, 1).map(v => +v));
console.log(fit(input, 2).map(v => +v));
console.log(fit(input, 3).map(v => +v));
console.log(fit(input, 4).map(v => +v));
```

outputs

```
[ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

These don't seem to exactly match your expected output though, but that may be because I'm assuming the flags in the array should mark the start of the chunk (i.e. can you fit N truthy values in the array starting from this position).

(See below, where e = your expected result, n = the output of my algorithm.)

```
input = [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
e = 2 = [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
n = 2 = [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
                         ====  ====  ====              ====
```

Comment: Thanks for this — this is closest as I want to output an array as per my question example. I need to clarify in my question though, as a 1 in the output can mean 'Yes, this slot could be the start of a chunk, or also be part of a viable chunk'

Answer (score 0):

You could use `some` method and then if the current element is `0` you can slice part of the array from current index and check if its all zeros.

```js
const data = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

function check(arr, n) {
  let chunk = Array(n).fill(0).join('');
  return arr.some((e, i) => e === 0 && arr.slice(i, i + n).join('') == chunk)
}

console.log(check(data, 3))
console.log(check(data, 4))
console.log(check(data, 5))
```